# Conting how many times recurion occured in tree

Tags: python, recursion

Hi I need help with this function:

```
    def order_of_succession(self, alive: Set[int], succesors: Optional[List[List[int]]] = None, order: int = 1) -> Dict[int, int]:
        if succesors is None:
            succesors = []
        for child in self.children:
            temp = []
            if child.pid in alive:
                temp.append(child.birth_year)
                temp.append(order)
                temp.append(child.pid)
                succesors.append(temp)
            child.order_of_succession(alive, succesors, order + 1)
        succesors = sorted(succesors, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
        succesion = {}
        for elem in succesors:
            succesion[elem[2]] = elem[1]
        return succesion
```

Only problem I have is that every time recursion is completed on one child order changes back to starting order on first child that was checked. This is output from that function:

```
{127: 1, 290: 1, 561: 2, 490: 2, 611: 2, 702: 2, 390: 3, 590: 3, 106: 4, 429: 4, 1000: 4, 101: 4, 898: 4, 253: 5}
```

I need order to be increased every time function is called but I dont know how to do it. Thaks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to do what you want with your current recursive API, since you can't readily return an updated `order` (since you're already returning something else). However, if you change things up so the recursive function is a helper to the main function, you can use a nonlocal variable to handle it properly:

```
def order_of_succession(self, alive: Set[int]) -> Dict[int, int]:
    successors: List[List[int]] = []   # both of these variables will be updated in helper
    order = 1

    def helper(person):
        nonlocal order                         # this lets us modify order
        for child in person.children:
            if child.pid in alive:
                successors.append([child.birth_year, order, child.pid])
                order += 1                     # which we do here
            helper(child)

    helper(self)

    succesors = sorted(succesors, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))    # the rest is unchanged
    succesion = {}
    for elem in succesors:
        succesion[elem[2]] = elem[1]
    return succesion
```

This isn't *quite* what you asked for, as I only update the `order` for living children. If you want the order to increment even when you recurse on a non-living child, you can move the `order += 1` line outside the `if` statement.